# How to add new base layer to QGIS OpenLayers from Freemap server

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a problem with adding a new layer to QGIS 2.6 OpenLayers and I need help. It is a source of maps www.freemap.sk

Examples of working with the server are:

```
http://wiki.freemap.sk/LayerAllInOne
http://wiki.freemap.sk/TileDistributionTest
```

Now I created a file freemap.html in the directory:

`~/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/weblayers/html`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers FreeMap Layer
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="qgis.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="OpenLayers.js">
    <script src="OlOverviewMarker.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var loadEnd;
        var oloMarker; // OpenLayers Overview Marker
        function init() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                theme: null,
                controls: [],
//                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
                units: "m",
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)
            });

            loadEnd = false;
            function layerLoadStart(event)
            {
              loadEnd = false;
            }
            function layerLoadEnd(event)
            {
              loadEnd = true;
            }

            var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
              "FreeMapTuristika",
              "http://a.freemap.sk/T/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
              {
                numZoomLevels: 16,
                eventListeners: {
                  "loadstart": layerLoadStart,
                  "loadend": layerLoadEnd
                }
              }
            );
            map.addLayer(osm);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution());
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(19.41,48.52).transform(
                                               new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")
                                                ), 11 );
//           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(4485,2841),13);
            oloMarker = new OlOverviewMarker(map, getPathUpper(document.URL) + '/x.png');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that QGIS does not open map:

[image: QGIS Freemap layer]

While the browser opens fine:

[image: browser showing data]

When I watched the network traffic, I found that QGIS was sending erroneous requests to the server:

```
GET /T/1/0/-1.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) QGIS2 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US,*
Host: a.freemap.sk

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 09:56:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://a.freemap.sk/core_allinone.php?/T/1/0/-1.png
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 09:56:41 GMT
X-Varnish: 10693744
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Content-Length: 235
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://a.freemap.sk/core_allinone.php?/T/1/0/-1.png">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
GET /core_allinone.php?/T/1/0/-1.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) QGIS2 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US,*
Host: a.freemap.sk

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 09:56:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Cache-Control: max-age=172800, public
Vary: User-Agent
X-Varnish: 10693746
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What is erroneous about the HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [quickmapservices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) in QGIS.
2. Open search panel (Web->QuickMapServices->Search QMS)
3. Type freemap
4. Push "Add button"

You can add your own services here: https://qms.nextgis.com/

[image]

[image]

Attention! The service has limits for zoom levels (8-16) and bounds.